# How get Eclipse src and rebuild (compile) it for a new language?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, src, rebuild

I try to recompile the eclipse src to use the ide ui for a new language or other interest).

how can I do it ?

Comment: or you want to make a plugin for Eclipse instead, like PHP Development Tools (PDT) ?

Comment: If you are looking for Eclipse build instructions, read this: https://kepler-project.org/developers/reference/kepler-and-eclipse#detailed-instructions-for-setting

Comment: exactly, personalize menu, reduce perspective, add perso plugin... like Aptana studio [link](http://www.aptana.com/) but for pascal language

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to modify the existing Eclipse Java code for a new language would be an enormous undertaking.

If you want to add support for a new language to Eclipse look at using a tool such as [Eclipse xText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/) to build Eclipse plugins for your language.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the source code of eclipse, it is available here under "platform"

https://git.eclipse.org/c/?q=platform

Probably what you are trying to do is reuse the GUI components that eclipse is built on top of.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/Rich_Client_Platform

Answer (score 0):

If it is for a new language, you should definitively have a look at XText. It's a framework to develop new language support in eclipse.

http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/